# Laravel translation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, lang

I added loadmore word and it doesn't translate it. It is in same folders like news and it translate that word. I don't know why it doesnt recognize it. SHould I do comting when I add new translate in lang: en, de..

```
    <h4 class="card-title mb-5">{{ __('dashboard.news') }} {{ __('dashboard.loadmore') }}</h4>
```

In lang: en, de
dashboard.php

```
  'news' => 'News',
    'loadmore' => 'Load more...',
```

It shows

News dashboard.loadmore

I tried everything like trans and so on.. Even if I change this 'News' in something else it still shows News.. Should I chenge something in someother file that I don't know for. This is code in Vue.js.
Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Clearing the cache may fix that, `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @user2682025 php artisan optimize:clear THIS HELPED ME.. Thank youu :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user2682025 `php artisan optimize:clear`  This helped me!!